# How to capture the exit status of a shell command in Java?

Tags: java, exit-code

I'm creating a Junit test file for my CSVreader. I'm reading the contents of CSV files and writing the contents into another file. I want to compare them using diff utility and I want to use the exit status of diff to know whether the contents are same or not. Generally $? gives the exit status but I don't know how to capture it and use it in my code. Can anyone help me in this regard?

This is how my code looks

```
 boolean hasSameContents = false;

    command="diff "+mp.get("directory")+"/"+fileName+" "+mp.get("outdir")+"/"+fileName;
    p= Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    p.waitFor();
```

After this I want to get the exit status and use it in a if condition like this

```
 if(exit_status==0)
     hasSameContents = true;
  else
     hasSameContents = false;
```

Even alternative suggestions appreciated. :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You're looking for [Process#exitValue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#exitValue%28%29)

```
String command = "diff "+mp.get("directory")+"/"+fileName+" "+mp.get("outdir")+"/"+fileName;
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
p.waitFor();
int exitStatus = p.exitValue();
```

Don't forget, you should read the contents of the `InputStream` even if you don't care, some processes will choke (not finish) until the output buffer has been read...

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the advice to read the InputStream! It saved my life on changing file permissions on large amounts of files.

Answer (score 5):

You can try using `ProcessBuilder` class to create a `Process`object, whose `exitValue()` should help you.

Answer (score 3):

Use method [waitFor() of class Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29). It returns an int, the return value of the process.

Answer (score 2):

`Runtime.exec()` and friends return a [`Process`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) object, which has an `exitValue()` method that returns the exit code.